# Cannot install mysql2 gem on Debian

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to get the gem mysql2 to install and I just cannot get it to work. Before trying to install I installed the following

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev
```

Then I go to install mysql2 and get

```
sudo gem install mysql2
```

Here is the error I am getting. Thanks

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file --      mkmf (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from extconf.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need ruby-dev

`sudo aptitude install ruby1.9.1-dev`

should fix it.